# Liquibase issue while running spring boot integration test

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

I am trying to run the integration test in spring boot which creates liqubase bean and run all the changesets. I get an error while running below change set in yaml file.
spring boot integration test run exception

```
   - changeSet:
        id: 2
        author: XXX
        changes:
        - sql:
            splitStatements: true
            sql: CREATE ROLE dba_user LOGIN PASSWORD 'dba_user';
            stripComments: true
```

Exception is

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE ROLE DBA_USER LOGIN[*] PASSWORD 'dba_user' "; SQL statement:
    CREATE ROLE dba_user LOGIN PASSWORD 'dba_user' [42000-196]
```

Why does it add [*] or is there some other issue? The same exception I get while running changeset to create a view.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is running against H2 database, which doesn't have `CREATE ROLE` feature.

BTW, I don't think it is good idea to create role via Liquibase. Liquibase is meant to be used for DB schema/data migrations, not for creating DB instance (where DB role creation falls as well). I would suggest to create role when DB instance is being created (doesn't matter if it is automated or manual).

Comment: Pretty sure H2 database has a `CREATE ROLE` feature

Comment: I got your point, I think but what about views that I created which has specific functions like 'filter' used for postgres but not available in H2? I get the same error for view as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL queries that not compatible with H2, you can use [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) to use PostgreSQL with your integration tests. It runs docker containers under the hood for your database needs in tests and you can query the containerized PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
preConditions:
        - onFail: MARK_RAN
        - not:
          - dbms:
              type: h2
```

I found a way to skip database specific script with this. So it won't run if it's h2.